# Match date and time from string with specific conditions

Tags: regex, coldfusion

**The problem:**
Have a long string of text and need to extract the date out of it. However, the string has multiple dates so certain conditions should be met to succeed.

**The strings with date fragments within the text are as follows:**

of Los Angeles 12/19/2018 11:39 AM She 
as a Unit 1/18/2019 8:30 AM 4 1.

**Using the regex below I can match two dates:**

```
<cfset dates = reMatch("(\d+/\d+/\d+)([^\s]([ ]{1,}))((1[0-2]|0?[1-9]):([0-5][0-9]) ?([AaPp][Mm]))(?=([ ]{1,}))(?=[0-9])", text)>
```

**Matched dates:**
12/19/2018 11:39 AM
1/18/2019 8:30 AM

I'm trying to match the date and time followed by one or more spaces and one or more digits (the second instance only), which would discard the first instance and leave me in a happy place. So far I've tried the following code but it discards both dates, so there something not quite right with the last blocks of regex:

```
<cfset dates = reMatch("(\d+/\d+/\d+)([^\s]([ ]{1,}))((1[0-2]|0?[1-9]):([0-5][0-9]) ?([AaPp][Mm]))(?=([ ]{1,}))(?=[0-9])", text)>
```

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: With all the capture groups `(\d+/\d+/\d+) +((1[0-2]|0?[1-9]):([0-5][0-9]) ?([AaPp][Mm]))(?= +\d)` https://regex101.com/r/CklyT6/1 Without the groups `\b\d+/\d+/\d+ +(?:1[0-2]|0?[1-9]):[0-5][0-9] ?[AaPp][Mm](?= +\d)\b` https://regex101.com/r/geQ4Xr/1

Comment: @The fourth bird Thank you very much!!! Your separate answer is working in your provided demo, but perhaps due to the different regex engine used by ColdFusion it does not capture the date as expected. However the code above is working just as expected. I will mark the answer as correct, but feel free to add the above comment to it, as it is the actual regex that solved my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have this part at the end of the pattern `(?=([ ]{1,}))(?=[0-9])` which are 2 separate assertions, where the first asserts 1 or more spaces, and the second asserts a digit directly to the right directly from the current position.

That will never be true.

What you can do is use a single assertion `(?= +\d)`, and if you don't need all the capture groups, omit them to get a match with a lookahead only.

Using a case insensitive match (as the only chars are `a` `p` and `m` and currently can be matched in any combination)

```
\b\d+/\d+/\d+ +(?:1[0-2]|0?[1-9]):[0-5][0-9] ?[ap]m(?= +\d)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fFLdB1/1)

Note that this is a broad match `\d+/\d+/\d+` which you might also refine using a pattern like showed [at this page](https://www.regular-expressions.info/dates.html).

The version with the capture groups:

```
(\d+/\d+/\d+) +((1[0-2]|0?[1-9]):([0-5][0-9]) ?([AaPp][Mm]))(?= +\d)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/CklyT6/1)